# MySQL: How to match data with regular expression string

Tags: mysql, pattern-matching

I have a postcode column in my table with values like `AB45*`, `RD4*`, `ADB567` etc.

Now I want to match my data with this column. The `*` means that a string starting with `AB45` should match with this column. If I use `AB45 45D` it should fetch a row containing `AB45*`

If I use `RD489` on my field, it should match with `RD4*` column value.

What can I use to achieve this requirement?

Comment: Have you tried REGEXP, SELECT 'RD489' REGEXP 'RD4*'; ?

Comment: Thanks @DaveStokes, Let me try it.

Comment: `SELECT 'RD489' LIKE 'RD4%';` or `SELECT 'RD489' REGEXP '^RD4.*';` [LIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like), [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

Comment: Thanks @Akina, Sorry but like does not work for me as I may have `RD4*` or `ABC4*` stored.

Comment: @DaveStokes, Your solution works, but there is one issue. I have `RD41*` and `RD42*` in my table. And if I enter `RD41` on front, it gives me two rows. It should give me a single result.

Comment: O_O `SELECT column LIKE 'RD4%'; ` will find `'RD4*'` value... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=01efca0843a209135fedf4e2bab70bb8

Comment: Thats the issue @Akina, My string is not fixed to three chars. It could be `RD41*` If I use like, it will give me everything starting with `RD4`

Comment: *My string is not fixed to three chars* WHAT string??? Column value or searching pattern?

Comment: My pincode column has values like ABC4* or RDTU22*. I want to match pincodes starting with above strings like ABC41 and ABC49 will match first column. RDTU225 and RDTU229 will match second column. @Akina

Comment: I understand that ABC4* / RDTU22* are stored in a table. But where are ABC41 and RDTU225? they are parameters which are transferred into prepared query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE patterns (pattern VARCHAR(16));
> INSERT INTO patterns VALUES ('ABC4*'), ('RDTU22*');
> SELECT * FROM patterns;
> ```
>
> ```
> | pattern |
> | :------ |
> | ABC4*   |
> | RDTU22* |
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE values_to_check (val VARCHAR(255));
> INSERT INTO values_to_check VALUES ('ABC41'), ('ABC49'), ('RDTU225'), ('RDTU229');
> SELECT * FROM values_to_check;
> ```
>
> ```
> | val     |
> | :------ |
> | ABC41   |
> | ABC49   |
> | RDTU225 |
> | RDTU229 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT values_to_check.val, patterns.pattern
> FROM values_to_check
> JOIN patterns ON values_to_check.val LIKE REPLACE(patterns.pattern, '*', '%');
> ```
>
> ```
> val     | pattern
> :------ | :------
> ABC41   | ABC4*  
> ABC49   | ABC4*  
> RDTU225 | RDTU22*
> RDTU229 | RDTU22*
> ```

> ```
> SELECT values_to_check.val, patterns.pattern, 
>        values_to_check.val LIKE REPLACE(patterns.pattern, '*', '%') does_they_match
> FROM values_to_check
> JOIN patterns;
> ```
>
> ```
> val     | pattern | does_they_match
> :------ | :------ | --------------:
> ABC41   | ABC4*   |               1
> ABC41   | RDTU22* |               0
> ABC49   | ABC4*   |               1
> ABC49   | RDTU22* |               0
> RDTU225 | ABC4*   |               0
> RDTU225 | RDTU22* |               1
> RDTU229 | ABC4*   |               0
> RDTU229 | RDTU22* |               1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1fd8babcbf92ebd0e3a0c6fcf1776a3b)*

PS. REPLACE() converts the pattern to the format clear for LIKE (replaces the asterisk with the percent sign).

Comment: Thanks Akina, this works as expected.